# VSPackage exception

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vs-extensibility

I'm working on a extension for Visual Studio and because of a bug in my code, the IDE crashed, and now every time that i want to load the extension i receive this message:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

At the moment that it crashed, everything was working fine loading the extension. The crash is related only to the logic of the application.

How could I load the extension again to be able to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to restart the experimental hive to its defaults state, now i'm able to find the bug...
In order the reset that hive it need to be executed the utility "Reset the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Experimental hive" that comes with the Visual SDK

Comment: You can also launch VS with "devenv /safemode" to prevent non-Microsoft supplied extensions from loading.